# Setting a value of a struct and then reading it (access violation exception)

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, struct

I've a problem in my program. I'm getting a exception that crashes the program. Firstly, i innitialize my struct object in my class header. Like so:

```
    struct Settings {
    DWORD AccesibilityMode;
    bool Raw;
    DWORD Type;
};

Settings * thread_settings = new Settings(); //Here im getting the pointer of the newly created 
object
```

Now i've innitialized what i need. Going on, now i need to set the variables of the struct pointer to the specific settings that i want (The struct is going to be used as a option/settings thingy). The struct pointer is private so i wrote a getter-method that returns the address of the pointer. It's written like this (in my .cpp file of the class):

```
Client::Settings* Client::Thread_Settings() {
return thread_settings;
}
```

Now, the method is a pointer that is accessible everywhere. I'm creating a object of the class and calling the address. Then im setting the vars like so (still no error to this point).

```
(object already defined)

client.Thread_Settings()->AcessibilityMode = 1; //Normally i have macros that are setted to these values
client.Thread_Settings()->Raw = false;
client.Thread_Settings()->Type = 33;
```

Lastly, the main function executes a method from the same class as the object struct pointer. These methods have if-statements that are checking the defined variables in the struct. These if lines are written like this:

```
if (thread_settings->Recv_BufferAccesibilityMode == 1 /*normally instead for 1 i've a macro*/ ) {
...... //rest of code
}
```

Now, i've got an access violation error that reads some unwritten memory (checked in an assembler) sometimes on 0x11C and sometimes at 0x12C. The error in vs19 looks loke this:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->thread_settings was 0x11C.
```

Do anyone have any thoughts? Appreciate any help :D

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful here.  There's probably a bug in code not provided.

Comment: my guess would be that `this` is null, i.e. whatever is calling `this->thread_settings` is inside a method being called on a null object pointer

Comment: I tried to change some things a little and instead of the method with if-statements checking directly through the original object i checked through the getter. Now the error looks like this.   (I think the pointer maybe is not valid)                                                                   `Exception thrown: read access violation.
Client::Thread_Settings(...) returned 0x11C`

Comment: If you want help provide a [mre]